# Is the usage "To + transitive verb" following nothing else grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitive-verbs

In the website [HKNA](http://www.hkna.org.hk/en/default.asp?page=home), 5 transitive verbs are used: promote, conduct, disseminate, undertake, facilitate. Is such usage "To + transitive verb" grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Why do you think they might be?

Comment: I think to + transitive verb should be followed by noun phrases. In that case, we can neglect grammar?

Comment: Transitive verb infinitives are used all the time without an object. *I want to direct!*

Comment: If, in fact, you hover over those 'menu' items, you'll see that each verb is used as the first two words of a specific aim that is displayed in the adjacent frame - and there it does have an object.

Comment: A transitive verb is always used with a direct object. "I want to direct!" does not make sense to me. What do you want to direct? I venture the verb should be followed by an object.

Comment: The problem is about that "menu". I found that ungrammatical.

Comment: See my answer below - it is ungrammatical, but that is expected in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right! The menu item headings are not grammatical.

But, if you hover over those 'menu' items, you'll see that each verb is used as the first two words of a specific **aim** that is displayed in the adjacent frame - and there it does have an object.

In English, *titles*, *headings*, *menu items*, *lists*, *etc.* often are not strictly grammatical - they are not intended or expected to be. They are just brief phrases or expressions that give you an indication of what follows.

But as a list of *headings* that lead you to a full sentence describing the aim properly, it is perfectly acceptable to use the verb infinitives in that way. They are not intended to be grammatical in that context.

Answer (score 2):

The menu that you mention has a title. **Aims**.

When we talk about "aims" we can use *the infinitive* to express what those aims are. For example, if I go on a diet some of my aims might be one or more of the following:

- **to look** slimmer
- **to lose** weight
- **to get** into a dress that is one size too small
- **to be** healthier
- **to lower** my cholesterol
- **to reduce** the risk of developing diabetes type 2

Likewise on the website menu mentioned it says the **aims** of the Hong Kong Nutrition Association are

> - *To promote*  "Optimal Nutrition for Better Health" based evidence-based scientific knowledge to the people of Hong Kong.
> - *To conduct* nutrition programs and research, and public education
>     projects in partnership with governmental and non-governmental organisations.
> - *To undertake* scientific research on links between food, diet and health. etc.

The verbs employed are indeed transitive verbs and they all have a direct object. If I could highlight or use a different colour for the (direct) objects, I would, but the "editing" tools available on ELU are pretty limited.

Therefore the menu is grammatical, although the following aim:

> "**To network** Hong Kong and international dietitians and nutritionists
>   [...]

doesn't sound right to me: it probably reflects modern-day usage and construction. If it were me, I would write "To form/to build/to create a network between ...".

Here is a link which discusses when to use the infinitive.

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html

If you look at point 4 you'll see that there is a list of verbs which take the infinitive. The first three listed are: afford, agree and **aim**.

Comment: Are "to promote", "to conduct", "to disseminate" by themselves ungrammatical?

Comment: One more question: are those verbs infinitive but not transitive on the menu (To + verb that part)?

Comment: What do you mean "by themselves ungrammatical"? As in without an object they do not make semantic sense? Used without an object these verbs will not complete a sentence. "I run" can stand alone; "I promote" is begging the question "What?" *What do I promote?* The main verbs; promote, conduct, undertake etc. in the menu are transitive and used in the infinitive.

Comment: That's exactly what I think. If one just says "to promote", it just doesn't make sense. What I thought ungrammatical was the part "to + transitive verb", which is followed by nothing else.

Comment: Yes, you're right but you're supposed to place your mouse over the word and the rest of the sentence/text is displayed on the left side. :) TrevorD in the comment section said as much.

Comment: What about "Transitive verb infinitives are used all the time without an object."? Is this wrong?

Comment: To the two down-voters, I would really appreciate if you could point out the errors, if any, in my answer. I'm quite puzzled. Seriously, I want to know. Thank you.

Comment: I've corrected "infinite" to "infinitive" in several places, and made minor layout & formatting changes - but I can't see anything else wrong.

Comment: @startanew You asked, is "Transitive verb infinitives are used all the time without an object." wrong? In my view it is, but I don't know what bib had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the spelling error, @TrevorD, I don't know why, but in my mind I only saw and read "infinitive"!